# Qlik Sense - create a list or graph that will load a table (QVD Object) when clicking the item

Tags: database, graph, data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense

I'm very new into Qlik sense and I want to know if this is possible.  So I did a data connection load to load a data into QVD objects (for example 60 tables of districts). When editing a sheet, is it possible to create a list that displays all districts and, when i click on a district, it will load that District table (object) which will expand more graphs that associate to that table? I hope this make sense. Please let me know if i should revise it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You want to load new data when some condition is met (in your case when on district value is selected) right?

If this is the case then I think that you can use `Dynamic Views`.

`Dynamic Views` allow you to load specific objects from a template app. So the workflow will be:

- prepare template app with all the objects that can be used in another apps. Including the script with placeholders where the selections will be passed
- in your main app - include these objects and set a threshold (in your case will be something like `count(distinct District) = 1`
- make selection in the `District` filed
- if the threshold is reached Qlik will pass the selections to the template app, it will reload it and the objects will be populated (how fast the objects will be populated depends on the script reload time of the template app)

[Documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/DynamicViews/dynamic-views.htm)

[Video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M60l1xjyNI0)

**P.S.0** Just to mention that `Dynamic Views` are "subset" of [On-Demand App Generation (ODAG)](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/DataSource/Manage-big-data.htm). The difference here is that ODAG will produce a new temporary app (again based on the template app) that the user can interact with and dispose whenever is needed (or Qlik will delete if after some specified time)

**P.S.1** If your data is not too big and you can allow yourself to load all the data for all Districts then you can use `calculation condition` for the charts that require only one District to be selected